# Counting the number of context switches in a c program when that program is executed

Tags: c, windows, process, context-switching

I want to output the number of context switches that are performed by the windows OS while executing my program.

Comment: I can't check right now but I seem to recall there's a performance counter for that, if you're on Windows. There are also counters on the chip itself but querying those is very environment-specific.

Comment: Thanking your immediate help. Is there any ways I can do that without using performance counter? Cause I don't know to work with it.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you don't know any other way either :) - here's some info to get you going: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx

Comment: Yes sir , I had this link before and thought there might be some means other than this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653951/1888362) will print the amount of context switches used by thread 0 of notepad (you can substitute any process and thread number you want in the CounterPathBuffer initialization) every second

Comment: That was very nice. Thanking you. I will work with it.

Comment: which windows os do you use?

Comment: I have used Sergmat sir's link to produce below results for notepad application:
I have extracted few lines from the o/p which showed instant changes"01/27/2013 18:45:47.523","26.862527043633797"<br/>
"01/27/2013 18:45:48.528","112.35574813481777"<br/>
If I write anything in notepad then the value is as below:
"01/27/2013 18:47:28.340","3418.9313164256719"<br/>
"01/27/2013 18:47:29.346","2197.8973136579948"<br/>

Comment: Sorry for messy output in comments , I was not able to print new line

Comment: What does the output 
01/27/2013 18:45:47.523","26.862527043633797"
indicate actually?? Does it mean 26.86.. context switches?? If that is the case , then why it is not a whole number??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Performance-counter for this purpose.

From : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28VS.85%29.aspx

You can view context switch data in two ways:

- The System\Context Switches/sec counter in System Monitor reports systemwide context switches.
- The Thread(_Total)\Context Switches/sec counter reports the total number of context switches generated per second by all threads.